# Accessing URI params in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url

(Learning RoR on my own, so pls forgive me if this is an obvious question)
I have an app to track books stored on shelves in libraries.  A request should come in like:

```
GET books/library_id   => shows all books on every shelf in a library
GET books/library_id/shelf_id  => shows all books on one shelf in a library
GET books/library_id/shelf_id/book_id  => shows a particular book
```

POST would use similar formats, except I will be using JSON in the POST body to supply the information (author, pub date, length, etc) for the book, shelf, or library

My question is, [:params] passed in to my controller seems to hold query (anything after a ?) and POST body parameters, but not the URL, which I need to parse and use to determine what to show.  Is there a way to get this out of the parameters?  I'm trying to avoid something like GET /books/?library_id/shelf_id

Comment: You can define a route such that params will additionally contain desired pieces of the URL that come before the `?`. For example, define a non-RESTful route like `get 'books/:library_id/:shelf_id/:book_id', to: 'books#show'`, and then BooksController#show can access params[:library_id], etc.

Comment: @user1801879 I don't think that is what's being asked for.

Comment: @antinome you are right.  I misread.

Comment: Thanks - between this and the answer below, I put it together and got what I needed.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a route so that `params` will contain specific URL fragments in addition to the query string and/or post data.

In config/routes.rb:

```
get 'books/:library_id(/:shelf_id(/:book_id))', to: 'books#show'
```

In app/controllers/books_controller.rb:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def show
    library_id = params[:library_id]
    shelf_id = params[:shelf_id]  # may be nil
    book_id = params[:book_id]  # may be nil

    # TODO: Do something with library_id, shelf_id (if present), 
    # book_id (if present).
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to process the URL with some very custom logic, you could have a wildcard route like `get 'books/*sometext', to: 'books#show'`. Then, in your controller action you could manually parse `params[:sometext]`. This would be considered "not the Rails way" but it's there if you need complete flexibility.

Finally, maybe it is worth mentioning that in your controller action you can get information about the request such as `request.path`, `request.fullpath`, `request.url`. But it doesn't sound like you need this in your case.

Comment: Done - my first question on StackOverflow, so I hadn't realized I needed to.  Thanks again!